# Converting String to Float or double value changes the decimal values

Tags: objective-c, string, floating-point, type-conversion

I am trying to convert string to float but it changes the decimal values.
e.g I have a string:

```
NSString *str = @"33.641832";
float value = [str floatValue]; //33.6418304
```

the value give me `33.6418304` instead of `33.641832`. I want to convert exactly as in the string.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the lack of float precision.

By my experience, Float are precise to the 7 significant digit approximatly.

33.641832 is stored as 33641832 *10^-6 so you have 8 significant digit (33641832).

You should use `double` if you want more precision.

Comment: The number is actually stored in binary, not decimal.

Comment: @SimonByrne Huh?  Are you serious?

Comment: @SimonByrne yes obviously, but it is store on 4 bytes: 1 bit for the sign, 8 for the exp value (base), and 22 bits for the significant digit. More info : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format.

Comment: Yes, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: It is actually stored as `1.051307201385498046875 * 2^5`

Comment: well it is stored as 0 and 1, we can all agree to that. we are all grown up dev here. so obviously, int float double, string, object, pointers are stored as binary. what I mean is that in order to "represent" the idea of decimal (you cannot cut a bit) the pattern used is to mutliply the decimal by a power of ten until you obtain the smallest integer (called the fraction). the fraction is stored as a binary in a part of the 4 bytes and the power of ten (called the base) is stored in another

Comment: My point was that the exponent is stored as a power of 2, not 10.

Answer (score 0):

See the table in [this post](http://www.exploringbinary.com/number-of-digits-required-for-round-trip-conversions/) by Rick Regan:

A `float` type is only guaranteed to accurately "round-trip" numbers with 6 significant digits. For `double`s, the guarantee is 15.